# sheet.Cell[,] wrapper class

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto, wrapper

I am trying to create a wrapper C# class for:

```
sheet.Cells[int row, int colmn].Value = "some value";
```

Any suggestions or should figure out some other way around it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment:
To clarify,
sheet is an Excel sheet. We have third party component to write excel reports. Now we need to update reports because this third party component got updated. What I need to do is to create a class that would mimic

```
sheet.Cell[int row, int colmn].Value = “Some Value”;
```

I am looking for something what is described in this article:
http://pietschsoft.com/post/2007/03/17/C-Give-your-object-a-Default-Indexer-Property.aspx

However, it gets complicated when indexer has two parameters.

This is the solution I came up with. This is probably not the best solution possible. However, I could not find other way around.

```
public class SheetClass  
{  
    public SheetWrapper Cells;

    public SheetClass(Worksheet _sheet)
    {
      Cells = new SheetWrapper(_sheet);
    }
}

public class SheetWrapper 
{
    private readonly Worksheet sheet;

    public PFCell this[int x, int y]
    {
        get { return new PFCell(this.sheet, x-1, y-1); }
    }

    public SheetWrapper(Worksheet sheet) 
    {
        this.sheet = sheet; 
    }
}

public class PFCell
{
    Worksheet ws;
    int x;
    int y;

    public PFCell(Worksheet ws, int x, int y)
    {
        this.ws = ws;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public object Value
    {
      get { return ws.Cells[x,y].Value; }
      set { ws.Cells[x,y].Value = value; }
    }
}
```

Then on a page I can do the following:

```
SheetClass sc = new SheetClass(sheet);
sc.Cells[1, 1].Value = "test";
```

If there a better way to accomplish this, please let me know.

Comment: what type is a sheet? what is the class you are trying to wrap? A bit more information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SheetWrapper
{
    private readonly Sheet sheet;

    public SheetWrapper(Sheet sheet) { this.sheet = sheet; }

    public object this[int row, int column]
    {
        get { return sheet.Cells[row, column].Value; } // add null checks, etc
        set { sheet.Cells[row, column].Value = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. And `Component One` charges people for doing simple stuff like this.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. You answered the question I asked. Unfortunately this is not exactly what I need and this is because I did not explain the problem thoroughly.

Comment: R_F: I don't see how this answer doesn't solve your updated problem.

Comment: Hello @abatishchev. I am sure you and @Gabe are right and I just do not know how to implement your solution. I end up with the code that I added to the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though you are trying to keep the exact same syntax as the standard Excel interop code, but make the cell indexing 2-based instead of 1-based. I don't know much about the Excel object model, but it seems like this should work:

```
public class SheetClass  
{
    RangeWrapper cells;
    public RangeWrapper Cells { get; }

    public SheetClass(Worksheet _sheet)
    {
        cells = new RangeWrapper(_sheet.Cells);
    }
}

public class RangeWrapper 
{
    private readonly Range cells;

    public Cell this[int x, int y]
    {
        get { return Cells[x-1, y-1]; }
    }

    public RangeWrapper(Range cells)
    {
        this.cells = cells;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Gabe. It is working, but it instantiate Excel interop Cell object through wrapper class, and that is the one I tried to keep off the page. I wanted to replace it with our own object but not to break syntax.